# How to get informations from DB using HTTP request in WSO2 ESB

Tags: database, esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to esb and to wso2. I want to call stored procedure and pass the parameters to the procedures from HTTP. I read about how to call stored procedure in the documentation but How can I pass parameters to the procedures using http request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the DSS service; the endpoint URL is provided on the Service Dashboard.  You have the option to access the service via HTTP/HTTPS.

You can create the endpoint on the ESB. You have options to access the endpoint in the following formats : POX, SOAP1.1, SOAP1.2, GET...

http://wso2.com/project/esb/java/3.0.0/docs/endpoint_guide.html